# TFS 2012 - Continuous integration with a website

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, web-deployment, continuous-deployment

I have a solution with multiple C# projects linked to a Website (File => New => Web Site).
I can use the continuous integration for all the C# project for now.

I would like to try the website from a different solution just for testing:

- I would like to know if the modification of an aspx or aspx.cs file will
  rebuild all the solution/project or just push the file which was
  modified on Azure.

[image]

It seams that the website will be rebuild, or will try to rebuild. 
Here is my website test solution [image]

and my Build Definition file :
[image]

So my question is, is it possible to integrate a website to a continuous integration system ? (TFS 2012)

If it's possible, What did I miss on the basic configuration ?(I didn't need any specific configuration for a WebApp project or a C# project)

I might need to build some files on the website (App_Code folder), But I would keep the possibility to deploy only the modified files (aspx, aspx.cs) without rebuild all the website and push everything on the server.

Let me know if you need any further information

Comment: I know this isn't an answer (hence the comment), but WebSite projects really don't play well with CI or automated deployment tooling.  Use Web Application projects in all possible circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

There is an article here [Continuous Deployment di Asp.Net web sites con TFS Build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/dn569268.aspx). It is in italian, but I think you may get the core using Bing/Google translator.

Comment: Google chrome translate me the webpage automatically :D. I just read the article quickly and it seams to be that I would like to do. I'll try it tonight or tomorrow. Thanks